# Don't have access to Pureftp using Unix credentials

Tags: pureftpd

I've been struggling with PureFTP on my Orange Pi Zero (Armbian 5.38, ubuntu), I don't know what should I do to enter with system credentials, I have "no" on PAMAuthentication and "yes" on UnixAuthentication, I dont know why it takes me as "Anonymous" (ANONY. OFF).

I'm not using pure-ftpd.conf (That's getting me off) and I just want to leave as simple as it seems to work. I don't want to use Virtual Users, so pure-pw didn't be configured...

I think that could be by the TLS option, I'm trying to set it "pure-ftpd -Y 0" but frozen my ssh connection... Why? there are similar commands of PureFTP that do the same behavior, the temperature is okay (33ºC)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally RESOLVED!**

Forget to know what was inside auth/70pam or auth/65unix, that was my error... (contains YES or NO)

> 1. Once changed 65unix to "NO" and 70pam to "YES"
> 2. Then on conf/PAMAuthentication set to "YES", and UnixAuthentication to "NO" (Because PAMAuthentication includes a
>      module with Unix authentication , by default)

Finally It didn't was what I'm looking for (Because I was looking for an user with chroot only on 1 directory), so I created Pure-FTP virtual users (First create an user for Linux (ftpuser) and then you can create multiple "virtual users" through pure-pw command, simple once you understand virtual users of pureftp).

Hope it helps!